# Обработка платежка с помощью revolut bank api

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно получать ссылку, на оплату товара используя пайтон, у меня револют банк, поэтому я [загуглил апи](https://developer.revolut.com/docs/accept-payments/tutorials/accept-your-first-card-payment/) этого банка. К сожалению я не совсем разобрался как можно это сделать, я только понял, что нужно давать запрос с данными и получать на выходе другие данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с помощью https://curlconverter.com/

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer [yourApiKey]',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

json_data = {
    'amount': 100,
    'currency': 'GBP',
}

response = requests.post('https://merchant.revolut.com/api/1.0/orders', headers=headers, json=json_data)

# Note: json_data will not be serialized by requests
# exactly as it was in the original request.
#data = '{\n          "amount": 100,\n          "currency": "GBP"\n        }'
#response = requests.post('https://merchant.revolut.com/api/1.0/orders', headers=headers, data=data)
```